# Swift - StoreKit verify customers offline

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, in-app-purchase

I'm using StoreKit and could list the products were registered in iTunes Connect and could simulate the purchase in SandBox.

I wonder if there is any way to determine whether an individual purchased the subscription application, even though offline.

I'm not using backend.

Do you know any way to check it?

Comment: I got a method to do this :)

Comment: And which method is that?